# Tier 2 dependent visa for child currently outside the UK

Tags: united-kingdom, working-visas, dependent-visa, children, documentation

My daughter is almost 3 and she was born in the UK - currently out of the UK for over a year with her grandparents. We are stuck at the moment with getting her a TB test because the country in Africa where she is residing have said that they have never done a TB test for a child separate from the parents' TB test. Has anyone ever been in this situation and what did you do?

Comment: Which African country? https://www.gov.uk/tb-test-visa